# Module lookup disabled by GOPROXY=off golangci

Tags: go

I have a vendor folder and CI/CD task Linter. Before push the folder to gitlab I did

```
go mod tidy
go mod vendor
```

My Linter task in Makefile looks like

```
@GO111MODULE=on GOFLAGS=-mod=vendor GOPROXY=off $(GOLINT) run ./... -v --max-same-issues 0
```

and I have no any problems when I start linting locally. But during CI/CD I got an error

> Running error: context loading failed: failed to load packages: failed
> to load with go/packages: err: exit status 1: stderr: go:
> github.com/jmoiron/sqlx@v1.3.1: module lookup disabled by GOPROXY=off

So i can't understand why I got this error

**Update**
I decided to remove the vendor, go.mod and go.sum. Then I created new go.mod and did

```
go mod vendor
```

After that I got the same error but with another package

> level=error msg="Running error: context loading failed: failed to load
> packages: failed to load with go/packages: err: exit status 1: stderr:
> go: github.com/fsnotify/fsnotify@v1.5.1: module lookup disabled by
> GOPROXY=off

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the settings of golangci modules-download-mode

this solution is set this variable to vendor mode:

```
modules-download-mode: vendor
```